# Expanding sections in UITableView, when expanding multi sections gets crash

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, crash

Trying to expand the section in UITableView, if single section is expanded and the closed then its ok but if a section is expanded then another without closing the previous it gets crashed.
Below is my code i am trying.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(!helpOn)
    return 1;
else
    if(section == selectedCellIndexPath)
    {
    return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [self.mHelpTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
else{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

UILabel *txtQues = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 30)];
txtQues.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtQues.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
txtQues.numberOfLines = 2;
txtQues.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

UITextView *txtAns = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 310, 60)];
txtAns.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtAns.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

txtQues.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];

if(!helpOn)
//if (indexPath.section==selectedCellIndexPath)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtQues];
        txtQues.text = [self.mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
else
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtQues];
        txtQues.text = [self.mArrQues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
    else{
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtAns];
        txtAns.text = [self.mArrAns objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
helpOn = !helpOn;

int ind = indexPath.section;
if(ind == selectedCellIndexPath)
{
}
else{
    helpOn = YES;
}
if(helpOn)
{
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.section;
[self.mHelpTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
else
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    //selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.section;
    [self.mHelpTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
}
```

Please guide for above i am no getting what us going wrong here already spent a evening and a morning. It gets crashed at number of rows in section method.
Below is error getting.

```
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message and check your logic in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. It says simple:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

It's hard to explain this any more plainly than it has been already by iOS. You're probably reloading the table, and then the table throws an error saying that the number of rows in secion 0 (your first section) is different between updates and it is not allowed. Check your logic that determines how many rows are in section 0 before and after you update the table.

**[EDIT]**

It looks like in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` that if `helpOn == YES` you set `selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.section`. Then you reload the table for that section and thus `numberOfRowsInSectio`: fires. In `numberOfRowsInSection:` if `helpOn == YES` and the `section == selectedCellIndexPath` you return 2. This could be why you're seeing one before the update, and 2 after the update.

Again, my advice is to check your logic in these two methods. You're changing the rows in one of your sections after you update it.

**[EDIT 2]**

Side note: Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is allocates a new cell every time. This is inefficient. Your `if(cell == nil) { // create new cell }` doesn't need an else.

Comment: i didn't get the point before update there was one row and after update two in section 0.

Comment: Check my aedit, it seems that your logic in `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning 2. I would set a break point and see if that if/else is entered correctly